# How to get combobox not to accept user input in Excel-Vba?

Tags: excel, vba, controls, excel-2007

Does anyone know what the properties are in the combobox that I can manipulate in order not to allow the user to key/type in any data?

Comment: What kind of combobox are you talking about? The combobox control or the one you can add to the Sheet with the "Data Validation" option?

Comment: @cularis its the one on the insert --> activex -->combobox

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Set the the Style of the combobox to `2 - fmStyleDropDownList`. This will disallow user input, and will also prevent (combobox).value changes via macro.

Comment: Is there a way to do this programatically?

Comment: @AndréTerra see the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7006888/how-to-get-combobox-not-to-accept-user-input-in-excel-vba/19322189#19322189) I just posted if you are still curious :)

Answer (score 6):

```
YourComboBoxName.Style = fmStyleDropDownList
```

or

```
YourComboBoxName.Style = 2
```

(that's from MS Excel Help)

Answer (score 5):

Here's a way to change this for each object on a worksheet:

```
Private Sub fixComboBoxes()
    Dim OLEobj As OLEObject
    Dim myWS As Worksheet
    Set myWS = Sheet1
    With myWS
        For Each OLEobj In myWS.OLEObjects
            If TypeOf OLEobj.Object Is MSForms.ComboBox Then

                OLEobj.Object.Style = fmStyleDropDownList
            End If
        Next OLEobj
    End With
End Sub
```