# VBA ActiveX ComboBox in Excel - how to allow user to type input but only accept valid items?

Tags: vba, excel, combobox, excel-2010

Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7006888/how-to-get-combobox-not-to-accept-user-input-in-excel-vba), I want to be able to do something only slightly different. I have a combo box which is going to have a lot of items (100+). This is a constraint I have to deal with.

Is there a setting to allow the combo box to prevent the user from adding new values but still allow typing, to help autocomplete or "select" the value when it's known by typing it in?

I know one way would be to write an event handler for each of these combo boxes to validate input but I don't want to have to tie this to *all* comboboxes I would like this functionality.

Comment: Set the `Style` to "drop down list" instead of "drop down combo"

Comment: @TimWilliams that still allows user input to remain, though it does not actually add it to the "values" list

Comment: Then you have some other setting which is set differently from my test...  I can't type anything which doesn't exist in the list.

Comment: Under the ComboBox Properties does it work when you configure MatchEntry = 0 - frmMatchEntryFirstLetter and MatchRequired = True  ?

Comment: Have you found solution to your question? If not, have you found if it is possible or not to solve it?

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin I have not and did not find a workaround :(

Comment: @enderland Hi I am facing same issue right now, May I know if you found any solution, I also tried with below answer setting prop values but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be done by changing the default settings of the ***[MatchEntry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/matchentry-property)*** and the ***[MatchRequired](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/matchrequired-property)*** properties of the ComboBox. I set

> MatchEntry: 1 - fmMatchEntryComplete

which will auto-complete as the user types in the text portion of the ComboBox based on the list that was provided to the ComboBox.

Setting

> MatchRequired: True

will validate any text typed into the text portion of the ComboBox.

So in the screen shots below you can see in the first one that I can type hu and the form autocompletes with hup2020 where the blue highlights what was autocompleted. You can also see in the second screenshot the dropdown list of my ComboBox and that hup2020 is selected as a result of my typing.

I can still type something else into the text portion of the combo box but as soon as I tap enter, the form pops up an invalid entry error box as shown in the last screenshot.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi @Nelda.techspiress I am facing with same problem statement  and I tried to set the propeties as per your answer, but i am not able to succeded in that. may i know how it worked at your end , is there anything more we need do for this.